# Can I override the parameter resolution of a particular state in AngularJS UI Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state with an optional parameter:

```
$stateProvider.state("clients", {
    url: "/clients?isActive",
    ...
});
```

When the state provider generates a URL, for example with `ui-sref`, I would like to be able to inject some code to determine from my own logic at that given point in time what the value of `isActive` is.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just determine it before calling ui-sref?

Comment: Because I don't want to have to decorate all my calls to `ui-sref` for a particular state with the parameter, I'd like to abstract that job into a service that my templates are otherwise ignorant of.

Comment: Use `ng-click` instead and `$state.go` in the click handler

Comment: That means you can't do things like right click->open in new tab or drag up as a bookmark etc, and I would still have to have some knowledge of the service in that I'd need to remember to wrap in the `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

Any state parameters passed to `ui-sref` are dynamic. For example

```
<a ui-sref="clients({isActive: someScopeProperty})"...
```

Will update the URL as `someScopeProperty` changes.

Plunker example here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/fTZD3S5Ejebi6LcAjBGP?p=preview